# Getting an error while including breadcrumb in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the material-ui/core version 3.9.0. & React version 16.13.1.

However, need to include breadcrumb. Updated the material-ui package to 4.0.2. However, when the app compiles there is no error. There is an error when the app loads.
The error is as follow-

```
SelectInput.js:288 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at SelectInput.js:288
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at SelectInput.js:287
at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:19731)
at commitPassiveHookEffects (react-dom.development.js:19769)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:22853)
at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
```

In debug mode the error is in the following file - node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Select/SelectInput.js file the error is showing as

```
React.useEffect(function () {
  if (!foundMatch && !multiple && value !== '') {
    var values = React.Children.toArray(children).map(function (child) {
      return child.props.value;
    });
    console.warn(["Material-UI: you have provided an out-of-range value `".concat(value, "` for the select ").concat(name ? "(name=\"".concat(name, "\") ") : '', "component."), "Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.", "The available values are ".concat(values.filter(function (x) {
      return x != null;
    }).map(function (x) {
      return "`".concat(x, "`");
    }).join(', ') || '""', ".")].join('\n'));
  }
}, [foundMatch, children, multiple, name, value]);







            <Select
            className={`clientSelector selectCombo ${classNames}`}
            value={value}
            renderValue={(value) =>
              items.find((d) => d.clientId == value).name
            }
            onChange={(e) => this.valueSelected(e)}
            disabled={clientDisabled}
          >
            {items.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={i} value={item.clientId}>
                  {item.name}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
```

Comment: Please show the code of your `Select`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your reply. The select code on the page is -

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check again your component, the error is `SelectInput.js:288 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`, so you should check the `value` variable that you pass to `Select` component at line 288 in `SelectInput.js`. Have you defined a variable named `value` in you component?